# Magento 2.1.2 Adding product will result to exception errors

Tags: magento-2.1

When I go to the backend of the site and navigate to products>catalog and click the add product button it will generate some errors.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: first check that class exists or not ?

Comment: I checked in the vendor of magento it does not exist

Comment: then copy that file from other magento of same version and paste it. Flush cache and check. May be you have installation error.

Comment: I tried a fresh install of magento 2.1.2 still that file I cant find it under vendor. Thanks

Comment: are you getting same error in fresh installation also ??

Comment: Yes I still got the same error

Comment: Do you have the same error after running bin/magento di:compile? or turning on developer mode via bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer